# Error createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS when under Android 4.2.2 application is started

Tags: android, android-studio

When debugging an Android application on the tablet there is an error, interrupt the operation of the application:

```
06-14 11:12:11.699 8073-8101/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 332
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1197)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1188)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1038)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1405)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)
06-14 11:12:18.039 8136-8167/? E/fb4a(:<default>):MmsConfig: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting
```

Googling, I found that this error is related to the OpenGL ES 2. The corresponding setting is available in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

I can not understand what the cause of the error occurring. If someone faced, it would be interesting to know exactly where and why this exception occurs?

Details:
- The application uses ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android version 100.0.0
- An error when placed in the Activiti MapView elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.at.agromap.MainActivity">

    <com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

- Used ASUS fonepad 7 tablet
- Android 4.2.2 API level 17

LAST UPDATE:
Problem has solved.
Below the answer from ArcGis developers forum

> This is a known issue for this release that has not found its way into
>   the release notes yet, we will update the release notes soon.   The
>   issue is that some devices do not correctly report their OpenGL
>   configurations to allow us to create our OpenGL context. We need to be
>   specific in creating the OpenGL context to allow many of our map
>   rendering features to work properly (particularly for things like
>   Vector Tiled Layers). We have implemented a solution which works on
>   most devices, but it will still be problematic on some, especially
>   older devices running older versions of Android.   Please try on
>   another device or the emulator.

Comment: Do you know if this fix has been released yet?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know,  because we`re used a previous release version of SDK in our project.

Comment: I have the same Problem with 100.4.0 and an Alcatel device.
Did you know anything i can do?

Comment: In my case there was one way to solve this - use another SDK version.